# Typing comment block in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just started to learn Java and I am a beginner to Eclipse.

When I start writing a source file, I start with a comment, for example:

```
/*
 *  This is the format of the comment I intend to get. 
 */
```

To do so, I type `/**/` and the take in cursor to the middle of it and press `Enter`.

To Eclipse's credit, it automatically starts the next comment lines with *, which is what I also want, however, here is something annoying happening which I haven't been able to figure out how to get rid of:

When I go to the middle of `/**/` and press `Enter`, it gives me

`/*
 * */
 */`

instead of intended

`/*
 */`

Which means that every time I have to go to the end and delete the extra `/*`. How can I avoid getting that extra `*/`?

Answer (score 1):

Just type:

```
/*
```

and then 'enter'.

It will start a comment block for you with just the single ending

```
*/
```

and your cursor in the middle.  At least, that's what I think you are asking?

Comment: Yes, you understood my question perfectly well. However, your solution doesn't work on my system. I'm using: Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1), Build id: 20140925-1800. Typing `/*` and `Enter` gives me just that: `\*` and cursor goes to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is typ `/*` and then `enter` and it will create what you want. You can also change the template for the way eclipse does comments (or the way elcipse does anything automatically). Follow the link if you want to learn more about how to customize the settings in eclipse.

http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcodestyle%2Fref-preferences-code-templates.htm

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Somehow " type `/*` and then `enter`" isn't doing anything more than literally " typing `/*` and then `enter`". I'm used to editingon Vim though so I have been typing `/**/` and `enter` in the middle of it for last couple of days when I started so may it be possible that Eclipse took note of it and changed its behaviour? Is it programmed to do stuff like that? Thank you for the customization link, it might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also comment out a line of code by placing the cursor anywhere on that line and pressing CNTL + /.

You can also highlight several consecutive lines and comment them all out by pressing CNTL + / (multiple single-line) or CNTL + SHIFT + / (Block commented out)

Comment: Thanks you for " CNTL + /." tip. That's useful. Block comment shortcut doesn't seem to be advantageous in terms of time saving to me though, not to mention it doesn't indent properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using shortcuts, makes your life a lot easier.

On Windows,

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> for single line comment
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> for multiple line comment

On Mac/OS X replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>⌘</kbd>

More shorcuts
http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html#link_7

Comment: yes but selecting bunch of lines and then doing "Ctrl + Shift + /" takes more time than typing /`**/` and `enter`. Besides, "Ctrl + Shift + /" isn't indenting the comments like it's supposed to be in header style comments. thanks for the suggestions though.